# Error: actual and formal argument lists differ in length. Object-Oriented Programming

Tags: java

So I am doing my first object oriented programming assignment and I am coming up with an error when I try and compile:
  winner = rps.pickWinner(userChoice, cpuChoice);  //***Your method
                        ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

**strong text**public class KyleAbelWeek10 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    RockPaperScissors rps = new RockPaperScissors();  //***Your class

    int numGames = 0;
    String userChoice = "";
    String cpuChoice = "";
    String winner = "";
    int userWins = 0;
    int cpuWins = 0;


    System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!\n");

    //Get odd number of games
    System.out.println("How many rounds would you like to play?");
    numGames = in.nextInt();

    while (numGames % 2 == 0) //Even number
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, number of games must be odd.  Please try again:");
        numGames = in.nextInt();
    }

    //Flush the buffer
    in.nextLine();

    //Play the game for the number of rounds the user entered
    for (int i = 1; i <= numGames; i++) {
        //Get the user and computer choices
        userChoice = rps.getUserChoice();  //***Your method
        cpuChoice = rps.getCPUChoice();   //***Your method

        System.out.println("Computer chooses " + cpuChoice);

        //Pick winner
        winner = rps.pickWinner(userChoice, cpuChoice);  //***Your method

        if (winner.equalsIgnoreCase("Tie")) {
            System.out.println("It's a tie!  Play again.");
            numGames++;
        } else {
            if (winner.equalsIgnoreCase("User")) {
                userWins++;
            } else if (winner.equalsIgnoreCase("Computer")) {
                cpuWins++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error in picking winner");
            }

            System.out.println(winner + " wins!");
        }

    } //end for

    //Print results
    System.out.println("\nUser wins: " + userWins);
    System.out.println("Computer wins: " + cpuWins);

    if (userWins > cpuWins) {
        System.out.println("\nThe user won!");
    }
    if (cpuWins > userWins) {
        System.out.println("The computer won!");
    }

    //Close game
    System.out.println("\nThank you for playing!");

} //end main

}

    import java.util.*;
public class RockPaperScissors
{
   public String getUserChoice ()
   {
      //Utility
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      //Variables
      String userChoice = "";


      System.out.println("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?:");
      userChoice = in.nextLine();

      while (!userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock") && !userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper") && !userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors"))
      {
          System.out.println("Sorry," + userChoice + " is not a valid entry.Please enter Rock, Paper, or Scissors.");
          userChoice = in.nextLine();

      }
      return userChoice;
  }
  public String getCPUChoice ()
  {

      //Get Random Number
      Random r = new Random ();

      //Variables   
      int randomnumber = 0;
      String cpuChoice = "";

      //Make a random choice
        randomnumber = r.nextInt(3)+1; 

        if (randomnumber == 1)
        { 
        cpuChoice = ("rock");
        }
        if (randomnumber == 2)
        {
        cpuChoice = ("paper");
        }
        if (randomnumber == 3)
        {
        cpuChoice = ("scissors");
        }

        return cpuChoice;
   }  
   public String pickWinner ()
   { 

      //Variables  
      String winner = "";
      String userChoice = "";
      String cpuChoice = "";

      //Decide who wins the round

       if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")) 
       {
           if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors"))
           {
              winner = ("user");
           }
           else if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper"))
           {
              winner = ("computer");
           }
           else
           {
              winner = ("tie");
           }

        } 
        else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper"))
        {
           if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors"))
           {
              winner = ("computer");
           }
           else if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock"))
           {
              winner = ("user");
           }
           else
           {
              winner = ("tie");
           }
        } 
        else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors"))
        {
           if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock"))
           {
              winner = ("computer");
           }
           else if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper"))
           {
              winner = ("user");
           }
           else
           { 
              winner = ("tie");
           }
        }     

        return winner;
   }
```

}

Comment: Some terminology: The "formal" parameter list is the list of parameters you write when you're defining your method.  The "actual" parameter list is the list of parameters you pass when you call the method.  If you had known that, the meaning of the compiler's error message would have been obvious.  Hope this helps next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RockPaperScissors` class defines:

```
public String pickWinner ()
```

meaning that it has no parameters. And yet your `main` calls it:

```
winner = rps.pickWinner(userChoice, cpuChoice);
```

*One* of those is wrong and will need to be changed.

---

Most likely it'll be the `RockPaperScissors` function since you *already* have the user and computer choices before calling it. I'd look into changing:

```
public String pickWinner ()
{ 
    String winner = "";
    String userChoice = "";
    String cpuChoice = "";
```

into:

```
public String pickWinner (String userChoice, String cpuChoice)
{ 
    String winner = "";
```

---

For what it's worth, you could make that function a little more readable with something like:

```
public String pickWinner (String userChoice, String cpuChoice)
    if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")) {
        if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors"))
            return "user";
        if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper"))
            return "computer";
        return "tie";
    }

    if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")) {
        if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper"))
            return "user";
        if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock"))
            return "computer";
        return "tie";
    }

    if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")) {
        if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock"))
            return "user";
        if (cpuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors"))
            return "computer";
        return "tie";
    }

    return "???"
}
```